# They're Watching Me

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, story

> When I woke up early in the morning, there were 15 of these staring at me.
>   I closed my eyes for a snooze, and when I opened them, there were still 15.
>   I arose to get dressed and when I turned back around, there were only 11!
>   As I ate my lunch, I saw 19 of them watching me in the kitchen.
>   Throughout the day, the least I ever saw were 6, the most: 21.
>   At one point I saw 8 of them; I wished I could be doing something other than watch them but there was nothing else to do.
>   Eventually I got tired of counting and, with 20 of them watching, I fell asleep.
>   When I woke up the next day, there were none at all! Getting up, I knew what I had to do to bring them back.

What are 'they' in the riddle? What did the author have to do to bring them back? In your answer, be sure to explain the count of them in each line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are

> The line segments on a digital clock that make up the numbers.

When I woke up early in the morning, there were 15 of these staring at me.

> This is 7:00 AM; 3+6+6 = 15.

I closed my eyes for a snooze, and when I opened them, there were still 15.

> A snooze is typically nine minutes, making this 7:09 AM; 3+6+6 = 15.

I arose to get dressed and when I turned back around, there were only 11!

> It's been only a minute now, making it 7:10; 3+2+6 = 11.

As I ate my lunch, I saw 19 of them watching me in the kitchen.

> Lunch happens around noon, or 12:00; 2+5+6+6 = 19.

Throughout the day, the least I ever saw were 6, the most: 21.

> The fewest happen at 1:11, the most at 10:08; 2+2+2 = 6, 2+6+6+7 = 21.

At one point I saw 8 of them; I wished I could be doing something other than watch them but there was nothing else to do.

> It's 11:11, make a wish; 2+2+2+2 = 8.

Eventually I got tired of counting and, with 20 of them watching, I fell asleep.

> You must have fallen asleep at 10:00 PM; 2+6+6+6 = 20.

When I woke up the next day, there were none at all! Getting up, I knew what I had to do to bring them back.

> Your clock batteries must be dead! Replace the batteries in your clock so you can see the numbers again.

Comment: Drat, too slow!  Well done!

Comment: I had that halfway typed out before you submitted, dang you.

Comment: Too easy after all. Gotta fix the calibration on this RiddleMaker(TM)!

Comment: @NeedAName you had no way of preparing yourself for the skill of a **puzzling God** like myself! ...no, but really, I liked the puzzle a lot. It was fun :)